# Convert Epoch date to standard format while retrieving data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have got a database with multiple entries. There is a date entry but while retrieving data it returns in Epoch format. I want it in standard format.

Here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{userid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody List<IterationInfo> getIterationInfoInJSON(@PathVariable int userid) 
{
    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory SF = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session= SF.openSession();
    Transaction TR = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query=session.createQuery("from IterationInfo");
    List<IterationInfo> listiterationinfo=query.list();
    session.close();
    SF.close();
    return listiterationinfo;
}
```

The data is returned in JSON.I want standard format of date not Epoch.Kindly guide me with where I need changes to be made

```
        public Class IterationInfo{

         private Date iterationstartdate;
         private Date iterationenddate;
                                           ---- Getters/Setters---
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to us @JsonFormat, you'll need Jackson in the classpath.

```
public Class IterationInfo{

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
  private Date iterationstartdate;

  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
  private Date iterationenddate;
}
```

See http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html

Comment: I added jackson in buildpath.Added the above notations.What I need to do in POJO/DAO class.I generated getters and setters.Anything to be changed in main controller class??

Comment: You should only need to change the Class that is being de-serialized (i.e. converted to JSon).  That's all you want to change.